# Correaltion between sparse variables

Tags: correlation, normalization, sparse

I have an Events x People matrix M, where a cell (e,p) gives the score of person j at event e. Let E be the total number of events. Each person has attended a lot of events, say 0.3*E at an average. However, the number of common events between 2 persons is very small (<

I am interested in the Pearson correlation between the scores of each pair of individuals. As the common attendance of any two persons is small, the correlation values computed using the common data points are off and rather noisy.

Consider an alternate approach, where I first normalize each persons score across all the events that the person attended and then take the pairwise covariance using the common data points. Note that if there are no missing values, this approach yields the pairwise correlation between people and is effectively the same as the first. I have 2 questions related to this approach:

- This second approach is similar to the first except that the mean and variance is computed from all the data points of a person rather than only the common data points, and hence, they will be more accurate estimates of the population mean and variance, and the approach will, therefore, yield more accurate correlation. Is this justified?
- In my implementation of this approach, I am getting some correlation values outside [-1, 1] though just slightly (1.2, -1.3, ..). There could be a bug in my code, but I was just wondering if that should even be mathematically possible?

Comment: The correlation must be between 0 and 1. It's a property of the correlation.

Comment: @Ertxiem-reinstateMonica Agreed. But I'm asking this in the context of the second approach mentioned in the question. Since the set of observations used for normalizing the variables is a superset of the ones used to compute the correlation, I was wondering whether it is possible that the property you mentioned could be violated.

Comment: If $R^2 \notin [0;1]$, then it's not a correlation.

Comment: @Ertxiem-reinstateMonica Ok, let's not use the term correlation and simply call it the output of approach. So, I'll rephrase my questions with that in mind. If, say, we know the true correlation of the variables (person scores), will the output of the first or second approach be closer to the original correlation matrix, measured by, say, the Frobenius norm? Secondly, in the second approach, is it mathematically possible for the output to be outside [-1,1]?

Comment: Take, as an example, $x_1=1; x_2=2; x_3=3$. The sample standard deviation of the set is: $s_x=1$. If you consider the subset $A=\{x_1,x_2\}$, $s_A = 0.71$, while if you consider the subset $B=\{x_1,x_3\}$, $s_B = 1.4$. So, when computing the "correlation" with the whole standard deviation $s_x$ you may be over or under estimating the true correlation, depending on the case, and so, it will be possible to obtain values outside of $[1;1]$ using your approach.

Comment: As for the proximity with the original correlation matrix, I'm sorry, but I don't have an idea on which is the best approach.

Comment: @Ertxiem-reinstateMonica Thanks, your explanation makes sense and is kind of obvious now that you have mentioned it.

Comment: I also got about to compare both the approaches and it seems that the second approach is more accurate when the number of common events between 2 persons is very small.